# How to do struct.pack and struct.unpack in cython?

Tags: python, c, serialization, struct, cython

I'm trying to convert a python module to cython, it does a lot of serialize and deserialize work.

Currently I have to do this:

```
import struct

from libc.stdint cimport (
    int32_t,
    int64_t,
)

cpdef bytes write_int(int32_t i):
    return struct.pack("!i", i)

cpdef bytes write_long(int64_t i):
    return struct.pack("!q", i)

cdef bytes write_double(double val):
    return struct.pack("!d", val)

cdef bytes write_string(bytes val):
    cdef int32_t length = len(val)
    cdef str fmt
    fmt = "!i%ds" % length
    return struct.pack(fmt, length, val)
```

Is there an equal in c lib to struct.pack and struct.unpack? What's the best way to do things like this in cython?

Comment: If it is only about integers I recommend asking especially for those, also in the title.

Comment: Hi I just updated the code to provide more detail. It's about int/double/string.

Answer (score 10):

I looked at the modules ([this](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/237284d0a73e472f836adc72f090432ae7c5dfad/Modules/_struct.c) and [this](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/940380184671a4310ddecef855fb6813f6cdae93/Objects/floatobject.c)) and just translated the code to Cython and removed the `PyObject` parts. In theory this should work, but some parts (like the `float` parts) I have no way of rigorously testing:

Some imports:

```
from cpython.array cimport array, clone
from libc.string cimport memcmp, memcpy
from libc.math cimport frexp, ldexp
from libc.stdint cimport int32_t, int64_t
```

Save some code with a fused type. It's technically not a stable feature, but it works flawlessly for me:

```
ctypedef fused integer:
    int32_t
    int64_t
```

This part tests the machine's endianness. It works for me, but that's hardly a complete suite. OTOH, it looks about right

```
cdef enum float_format_type:
    unknown_format,
    ieee_big_endian_format,
    ieee_little_endian_format

# Set-up
cdef array stringtemplate = array('B')
cdef float_format_type double_format

cdef double x = 9006104071832581.0

if sizeof(double) == 8:
    if memcmp(&x, b"\x43\x3f\xff\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05", 8) == 0:
        double_format = ieee_big_endian_format
    elif memcmp(&x, b"\x05\x04\x03\x02\x01\xff\x3f\x43", 8) == 0:
        double_format = ieee_little_endian_format
    else:
        double_format = unknown_format

else:
    double_format = unknown_format;
```

(The `stringtemplate` is used to be able to make `bytes` objects quickly)

This part's simple:

```
cdef void _write_integer(integer x, char* output):
    cdef int i
    for i in range(sizeof(integer)-1, -1, -1):
        output[i] = <char>x
        x >>= 8

cpdef bytes write_int(int32_t i):
    cdef array output = clone(stringtemplate, sizeof(int32_t), False)
    _write_integer(i, output.data.as_chars)
    return output.data.as_chars[:sizeof(int32_t)]

cpdef bytes write_long(int64_t i):
    cdef array output = clone(stringtemplate, sizeof(int64_t), False)
    _write_integer(i, output.data.as_chars)
    return output.data.as_chars[:sizeof(int64_t)]
```

The `array` is similar to `malloc` but it's garbage collected :).

This part I mostly have no idea about. My "tests" passed, but it's mostly hope:

```
cdef void _write_double(double x, char* output):
    cdef:
        unsigned char sign
        int e
        double f
        unsigned int fhi, flo, i
        char *s

    if double_format == unknown_format or True:
        if x < 0:
            sign = 1
            x = -x

        else:
            sign = 0

        f = frexp(x, &e)

        # Normalize f to be in the range [1.0, 2.0)

        if 0.5 <= f < 1.0:
            f *= 2.0
            e -= 1

        elif f == 0.0:
            e = 0

        else:
            raise SystemError("frexp() result out of range")

        if e >= 1024:
            raise OverflowError("float too large to pack with d format")

        elif e < -1022:
            # Gradual underflow
            f = ldexp(f, 1022 + e)
            e = 0;

        elif not (e == 0 and f == 0.0):
            e += 1023
            f -= 1.0 # Get rid of leading 1

        # fhi receives the high 28 bits; flo the low 24 bits (== 52 bits)
        f *= 2.0 ** 28
        fhi = <unsigned int>f # Truncate

        assert fhi < 268435456

        f -= <double>fhi
        f *= 2.0 ** 24
        flo = <unsigned int>(f + 0.5) # Round

        assert(flo <= 16777216);

        if flo >> 24:
            # The carry propagated out of a string of 24 1 bits.
            flo = 0
            fhi += 1
            if fhi >> 28:
                # And it also progagated out of the next 28 bits.
                fhi = 0
                e += 1
                if e >= 2047:
                    raise OverflowError("float too large to pack with d format")

        output[0] = (sign << 7) | (e >> 4)
        output[1] = <unsigned char> (((e & 0xF) << 4) | (fhi >> 24))
        output[2] = 0xFF & (fhi >> 16)
        output[3] = 0xFF & (fhi >> 8)
        output[4] = 0xFF & fhi
        output[5] = 0xFF & (flo >> 16)
        output[6] = 0xFF & (flo >> 8)
        output[7] = 0xFF & flo

    else:
        s = <char*>&x;

        if double_format == ieee_little_endian_format:
            for i in range(8):
                output[i] = s[7-i]

        else:
            for i in range(8):
                output[i] = s[i]
```

If you can understand how it works, be sure to check it yourself.

Then we wrap it as before:

```
cdef bytes write_double(double x):
    cdef array output = clone(stringtemplate, sizeof(double), False)
    _write_double(x, output.data.as_chars)
    return output.data.as_chars[:sizeof(double)]
```

The string one is actually really simple, and explains why I set it up as I did above:

```
cdef bytes write_string(bytes val):
    cdef:
        int32_t int_length = sizeof(int32_t)
        int32_t input_length = len(val)
        array output = clone(stringtemplate, int_length + input_length, True)

    _write_integer(input_length, output.data.as_chars)
    memcpy(output.data.as_chars + int_length, <char*>val, input_length)

    return output.data.as_chars[:int_length + input_length]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're only packing one type of data per command (eg. a group of `ints`, then a group of `floats` etc), you can use `array.array()` for faster results, either via Python or Cython.

Source: 
[Serialize a group of integers using Cython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48371251/serialize-a-group-of-integers-using-cython)