# Serialize a group of integers using cython

Tags: python, serialization, struct, cython

I saw this sample code from the [Pyrobuf](https://techblog.appnexus.com/pyrobuf-a-faster-python-protobuf-library-written-in-cython-d9fa908537c9) page for serializing an integer ~3 times faster than via `struct.pack`:

```
def ser2(): 
    cdef int x = 42 
    return (<char *>&x)[:sizeof(int)]
```

I was wondering how this could be done for a group of integers.
I saw cython has `int[:]` and `array.array` types, but I still don't understand how do I take a list of integers for example, and get the same (but faster) result as via `struct.pack('i', *num_list)`. `map()` didn't seem work faster for me, and I'm wondering how this should be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you want to speed up the following (Python3):

```
import struct 
lst=list(range(100))  #any other size
struct.pack('i'*len(lst), *lst)
```

without `struct` and cython you could achieve it as following in python:

```
import array
bytes(array.array('i', lst))
```

this is however somewhat slower than  the `struct`-module:

```
>>> %timeit struct.pack('i'*len(lst), *lst)
2.38 µs ± 9.48 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
>>> %timeit bytes(array.array('i',lst))
3.94 µs ± 92 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

However, cython can be used to speed up the creation of the `array`, for the documentation see [here(arrays)](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/array.html) and [here(str/bytes)](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/strings.html):

```
 %%cython
 import array
 from cpython cimport array
 def ser_int_list(lst):
    cdef Py_ssize_t n=len(lst)
    cdef array.array res=array.array('i')
    array.resize(res, n)  #preallocate memory
    for i in range(n):
       res.data.as_ints[i]=lst[i]            #lst.__get__() needs Python-Integer, so let i be a python-integer (not cdef)
    return res.data.as_chars[:n*sizeof(int)] # str for python2, bytes for python3
```

The timings show the following performance:

```
#list_size    struct-code    cython-code    speed-up
     1           343 ns         238 ns        1.5
    10           619 ns         283 ns         2
   100          2.38 µs        2.38 µs        3.5
  1000          21.6 µs        5.11 µs         4
 10000           266 µs        47.5 µs        5.5
```

i.e. cython provides some speed-up, from `1.5` for small list up to `5.5` for large lists.

Probably this could be tweaked even further, but I hope you get the idea.

---

Testing code:

```
import struct
for n in [1, 10,10**2, 10**3, 10**4]:
    print ("N=",n)
    lst=list(range(n))
    print("struct:")
    %timeit struct.pack('i'*len(lst), *lst)
    print("cython:")
    %timeit ser_int_list(lst)
```

Comment: Thanks!  bytes(res) is however not what I need, but res.tostring(). Could you perhaps advise on how I can instead "grab" the underlying bytes with a similar casting trick as with the single int? I suspect it might be faster

Comment: @Jay Sorry, I assumed Python3. I edited my answer, so it works with both Python2 (returns str) and Python3 (returns bytes). However, the same as with int-example, the memory is copied behind the scenes.with `str`.

Comment: @Jay  If you would like to avoid copying I think you need to have a slightly different interface - I don't think you can do it with `str`. However, you should time it first, to check whether it is worth it: my guess overhead maybe of around 10% for very small list and less for bigger lists.

Comment: Thank you, it works now. Unfortunately, I did not see a time difference between the cython function and python's own array.array('i', lst).tostring() for big lists of numbers when trying this out. Guess cython doesn't add any benefit in this specific case, though the cython know-how is quite useful